# Intelligent Appointment Management Error

Tags: health-cloud, bookappointment

I'm setting up Intelligent Appointment Management, but when I'm testing on a personal account, I get this error: "No possible slots for an internal provider and an external visit type. Please try searching again, using the same type for both".

[image]

Comment: Is this error seen for a specific person account or across all person accounts?

Comment: Hello, it was solved by taking other fields from the address

Comment: Hi @NatalieCuervo, Would you mind elaborating on your solution comment please? 'taking other fields from the address'. We are faced with the same error/warning.

Answer (score 0):

Check **Work type code set bundle** record. In that field **Scheduling system** value should be **Salesforce**.